# A tricky analysis problem

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $n,m \in \mathbb{N}, n>4,m\geq1$

We define

\begin{equation}
  f_i(x)=\begin{cases}
    m_ix, & \text{if $x \in\left[\frac{1}{m_i}\left(j+\frac{1}{n}\right),\frac{1}{m_i}\left(j+1-\frac{1}{n}\right)\right]$}
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}

where $x\in \mathbb{R}$, $i$ runs from $1$ to $n-1$ and $j$ runs from $0$ to $m_i-1$.

Find $a$ where $f_i(a)$ exists for all $i$.

For instance, let $n=5$. Then there are $n-1$ ($4$ in this case) number of functions $f_i(x)$ and $m_i$. Let $m_1=1$, $m_2=2$, $m_3=4$ and $m_4=5$. Then

[image]

$f_i(x)$ all exist when $x$ is in the orange strips.

The diagram is not drawn immaculately and the width of the first orange should be equal to the width of the second orange strip due to symmetry.

This question asks for the existence of such a strip in general.

Comment: What is $m_i$? Why isn't $j$ taking part in the definition of $f_i(x)$?

Comment: It is very difficult to understand the statement of this question.

Comment: Wait... Let me illustrate it with an example.

Comment: Your problem seems ill defined to me. $f_i(x)$ is so far I can tell not uniquely defined by the choice of $i$, the choice of $m_i$ also plays a role. For instance, for your case $n=5$, one can perfectly construct a function with $m_i=3$.

Comment: For the strongest case, consider all $f_i(x)$ unique, i.e., all $m_i$ are uniquely defined.

Comment: Why is $m\ge1$ introduced, but not used?

Comment: Should be $m_i\geq 1$.

Answer (score 2):

The domain of $f_i$ seems to be $\bigcup_{j=0}^{m_i-1}\left[j+\frac{1}{n},j+1-\frac{1}{n}\right]$.

Since the intervals $\left[j+\frac{1}{n},j+1-\frac{1}{n}\right]$ are all disjoint we have $$\bigcap_{i=1}^{n-1} \left(\bigcup_{j=0}^{m_i-1}\left[j+\frac{1}{n},j+1-\frac{1}{n}\right]\right) = \bigcup_{j=0}^{m-1} \left[j+\frac{1}{n},j+1-\frac{1}{n}\right],$$
where $m = \min\{m_1,\ldots,m_{n-1}\}$.

Hence $f_i(a)$ is defined for all $i\in\{1,\ldots,n-1\}$ for all $a\in \bigcup_{j=0}^{m-1} \left[j+\frac{1}{n},j+1-\frac{1}{n}\right]$, where $m = \min\{m_1,\ldots,m_{n-1}\}$.

Comment: Utmost apologies for a late update... I had a mistake in the question which made the diagram and the question incoherent. Can you help with the solution now?